# What is meant by "increases exponentially with time"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling, convention

The following qeustion states "you may assume Phoebe's speed increases exponentially with time", but only provides 2 data points from which to derive the model. Is this question lacking enough constraints (data points)? As I am sure I can create many exponential models that pass through those 2 points ($(0,4230)$ and $(10,6850)$). Or, does the statement "increases exponentially with time" costrain the model to the general form $f(x)=a*b^x$? My gut feeling was that $f(x)=a*b^x+c$ would also be valid form per the question's verbage.

> *Phoebe's Next Rocket Problem* Phoebe Small is out Sunday driving in her rocket ship. She fills up with fuel at the Scorpion Gulch Rocket Fuel Station, and takes off. When she starts the last stage of her rocket, she is going 4230 miles per hour. Ten seconds later she is going 6850 mph. While the last stage is running, you may assume Phoebe's speed increases exponentially with time. Derive a model, $f(x)$, for the rocket's velocity while the last stage is running.

Comment: As the answers indicate, $a(b^x)+c$ is not exponential for the purposes of this question. This comment is just to add that it *could* be considered exponential for other contexts. We might say, for example, that an algorithm with run-time $a(b^x)+c$ is exponential in time complexity, because asymptotically, it is exponential.

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment, can you clarify. To me, the verbage "increases exponentially with time" only indicates that some sort of exponential relationship exists between time and velocity. And, indeed, an exponential relationship exists between both $f(x)=a(b^x)$ and $g(x)=a(b^x)+c$.  Are you saying that by convention  and in this context the phrasing "increases exponentially with time" always means $f(x)=a(b^x)$? If so, this being a math thing, I assume this convention is defined somewhere. From a purely English language perspective, I think my understanding is more correct.

Comment: I'm afraid this is something you can only get a good feel for through experience. And there's no such thing as a "purely English language perspective"; no language is pure (as much as the French academy would like to insist otherwise), but English particularly not. ¶ The plain fact is that exponential is almost surely being used in the sense "exactly proportional to *the* exponential function" whereas in other contexts, it might just be asymptotically so. You can argue this is an annoying ambiguity with English, and I won't disagree, but that doesn't stop it being ambiguous.

Comment: One last thing: Mathematics *can* be precise, but in communication between humans, we use terminology that is a mixture of precise and loose. I agree it's annoying that you can't always tell, but over time, we learn to deal with it. (For a better skew toward precise, consider programming. But that comes with its own heartaches.)

Comment: @BrianTung Thank you! Your followups directly confronted my confusions. Would the following be a mathmaticians thought process regarding how they resolve this question's ambiguity?
"The question is expecting a single answer. Since many answers exist, the simplist interpretation of the question results in the assumptioin that $f(x)$ has the form $f(x)=a(b^x)$?"
I was 100% not expecting the answers I received. I am glad I asked. I had assumed mathmatiticans were even more precise than programmers.

Comment: Programmers talk to machines (or, when they do, they're aware they have to talk precisely). Mathematicians talk to other mathematicians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x)=a\cdot b^x+c$ is not exponential.  In fact, if $c$ is quite large it hardly increases at all.  You are expected to assume $f(x)=a\cdot b^x$.  Plug the $x,f(x)$ values into this to give two equations in two unknowns, $a,b$ and solve them simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "increases exponentially with time" does indeed constrain the model to the general form $ f (x) = a \cdot b^x $. A possible definition of "increases exponentially with time" would be that $ f (x) $ solves a differential equation of the form:
$$ \forall x, \quad f' (x) = \beta \cdot f(x) $$
for some value of the parameter $\beta$. Your first model may be written as:
$$ f(x) = a \cdot b^{x} = a \cdot \left( e^{\log b} \right)^x = a \cdot e^{\log b \cdot x} $$
which indeed solves the above differential equation for $ \beta = \log b $. On the other hand, for your second model the derivative $ f' (x) $ is not proportional to $ f ( x ) $ because the constant term drops when we take the derivative. Thus, by this definition, your second model would not be considered to increase exponentially with time.